# Mailchimp predetermined signup form values

Tags: php, api, post, mailchimp

I'm trying to follow this: https://mailchimp.com/help/determine-webpage-signup-location/ so that my subscribers can be assigned a sign up location. I've done everything correctly but when I look in my database, the sign up location is blank.

My form action:

```
<form action="https://xxxxxx.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=1801428b6322f0614eab&amp;id=f99e70&SIGNUP=Homepage" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
```

I've followed the steps but the database is blank for Sign Up Location. My survey set up:

[image: Survey set up]

Comment: are you sure you catch u, ud and SIGNUP as $_GET variable?

Comment: It turns out I couldn't do it because I was only sending my email value through, whereas the form required more than 1 mandatory field to be filled in so it was giving me and error . However the above works correctly.